# Корректная работа с AsyncHttpClient в Android приложении.

Tags: android-sdk, android

Здравствуйте, уважаемые Хешкодовцы!

Решил использовать библиотеку AsyncHttpClient и уперся в одну проблему. Получаю json набор данных в ответ с сервера, как распарсить его, знаю, а вот что с ним делать дальше? Допустим, я хочу что-то отбразить в приложении на основе этих данных.

---

*Читал про организацию калбэков, но не понял, как именно сделать их для текущей структуры.*

---

**Вот базовый класс для АПИ**

```
public class BaseRestClient
{
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://xxx.ru/";

    private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
        return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
    }
}
```

**Вот пример класса запроса АПИ**

```
public class UserRestClient
{
    public void userLogin() throws JSONException {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("method", "login");
        params.put("login", "asdasd");
        params.put("password", "sadadasdasd");

        BaseRestClient.get("api/mobile", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    // If the response is JSONObject instead of expected JSONArray
                    String status = response.getString("success");

                    **// И вот тут я хочу что то сделать в Апе на основе этих данных**
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray timeline) {
                // Pull out the first event on the public timeline
                //JSONObject firstEvent = timeline.get(0);
                //String tweetText = firstEvent.getString("text");

                // Do something with the response
                System.out.println(timeline);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONArray errorResponse) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                System.out.println(errorResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                System.out.println(errorResponse);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.println(responseString);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**Вот так вызываю в активити**

```
try {
    UserRestClient user = new UserRestClient();
    user.userLogin();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Я бы порекомендовал использовать `BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler<T>` вместо  `JsonHttpResponseHandler`.
2. JsonHttpResponseHandler - это и есть твой колбэк, который сработает, когда придет результат, обработаешь (возможно) ты его в `onSuccess` и в этом же методе сможешь прописать код, который выведет результат на экран или передать дальше в методы для обработки.
3. Так как это колбэк, возможны ошибки NPE (когда фрагмента или активити уже нету на экране, а результат пришел с опозданием). Тогда лучше использовать для обработки otto-bus или аналоги или свой листнер, или проверять на null.

Добавлю свой колбэк, может, кому пригодится:

```
/**
 * Created by gorets on 17.01.2015.
 */
public class ApiResponse<T> extends BaseJsonHttpResponseHandler<T> {
    private static final String TAG = ApiResponse.class.getSimpleName();

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public ApiResponse(final Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final int statusCode, final Header[] headers, final String rawJsonResponse, final T response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(final int statusCode, final Header[] headers, final Throwable throwable, final String rawJsonData, final T errorResponse) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure method was fire in " + clazz.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected T parseResponse(final String rawJsonData, final boolean isFailure) throws Throwable {
        return isFailure ? null : BaseFragment.fromJson(rawJsonData, clazz);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы говорите о том, что нужно переопределить класс. В этом нет какойлибо предвзятости можно и переопределить. НО суть остается таже. Как по onSucess передать результат в активити (причем не просто передать а выполнить какое либо действие).

Comment: я же написал про это, надо написать свой колбэк, который будет срабатывать в активити или вызывать метод АПИ в активити и в методе onSucess  прописать логику работы с UI